# how to call two adapter in one class android

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter, baseadapter

i'm trying to call more than one adapter in one of my activity, when i run it, only one adapter running and others doesn't run.. this is my layout :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/medium_gray">

        <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/unitlink1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">
     <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textColor="#FF0000"
                android:text="TRANSAKSI"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:divider="#000000"
                 android:dividerHeight="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>

   <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            style="@style/size10ptWhite3dpBold"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight=".35"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:orientation="vertical" 
            android:paddingTop="5dip"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip">

        <!--Kolom 1-->
        <TextView
            android:text="Transaksi"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:paddingTop="10dip"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip" />

    </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Kolom 2 -->
        <LinearLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                style="@style/size10ptWhite3dpBold"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_weight=".35"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingTop="5dip"
                android:paddingBottom="10dip" >

        <TextView
            android:text="Jumlah"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:paddingTop="10dip"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Tanggal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#b5b5b5"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip"/>
    </LinearLayout> 

        <!-- Kolom 3 -->
    <LinearLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                style="@style/size10ptWhite3dpBold"              
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_weight=".30"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingTop="5dip"
                android:paddingBottom="10dip">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/jumlah_unit"
            android:text="Jumlah Unit"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:paddingTop="10dip"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip" 
            android:gravity="right"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/harga_unit"
            android:text="Harga Unit"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColor="#b5b5b5"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip"/>

    </LinearLayout>

        </TableRow>
        <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <include layout="@layout/line"/>
            </LinearLayout>

       <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="#000000"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:clickable="false"/>
       </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/unitlink2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">
     <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/title1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textColor="#FF0000"
                android:text="RINGKASAN DANA TRANSAKSI"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:divider="#000000"
                 android:dividerHeight="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>

   <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            style="@style/size10ptWhite3dpBold"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight=".35"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:orientation="vertical" 
            android:paddingTop="5dip"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip">

        <!--Kolom 1-->
        <TextView
            android:text="Jenis dana Transaksi"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:paddingTop="10dip"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip" />

    </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Kolom 2 -->
        <LinearLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                style="@style/size10ptWhite3dpBold"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_weight=".35"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingTop="5dip"
                android:paddingBottom="10dip" >

        <TextView
            android:text="Total Unit"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:paddingTop="10dip"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Harga Unit"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#b5b5b5"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip"/>
    </LinearLayout> 

        <!-- Kolom 3 -->
    <LinearLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                style="@style/size10ptWhite3dpBold"              
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_weight=".30"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingTop="5dip"
                android:paddingBottom="10dip">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/jumlah_unit1"
            android:text="Nilai POLIS"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:paddingTop="10dip"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip" 
            android:gravity="right"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/harga_unit1"
            android:text="Tanggal NAB"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColor="#b5b5b5"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip"/>

    </LinearLayout>

        </TableRow>
        <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <include layout="@layout/line"/>
            </LinearLayout>

       <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="#000000"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:clickable="false"/>
       </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

this is how i call two adapter in one class :

```
(jenis_link.equals("unit_link")) {
                        RingkasanUlinkVariabel VarRKS = null;
                        JSONArray rks_ulink = transaksi.getJSONArray("rks_ulink");
                        for (int j=0; j<rks_ulink.length();j++){
                            JSONObject rks = rks_ulink.getJSONObject(j);
                            VarRKS= new RingkasanUlinkVariabel(rks.optString("lji_invest"),
                                    rks.optString("total_unit"),
                                    rks.optString("harga_unit"),
                                    rks.optString("nilai"),
                                    rks.optString("tgl"));
                            ListRingkasan.add(VarRKS);
                            System.out.println("Adam levine");

                            setContentView(R.layout.unitlinklist);
                            LinearLayout unitlink1=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.unitlink2);
                            list=(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);

                            RingkasanAdapter ringkasan = new RingkasanAdapter(InvestasiViewerEpolicy.this, 
                                    ListRingkasan);
                            list.setAdapter(ringkasan);
                        }
                            UnitLinkVariabel VarUnit = null;
                            JSONArray ulink = transaksi.getJSONArray("ulink");
                            for (int k=0; k<ulink.length();k++){
                            JSONObject unit = ulink.getJSONObject(k);
                            VarUnit= new UnitLinkVariabel(unit.optString("transaksi"),
                                    unit.optString("jumlah"),
                                    unit.optString("tgl_nab"),
                                    unit.optString("jumlah_unit"),
                                    unit.optString("harga_unit"));
                            ListUnitLink.add(VarUnit);
                            System.out.println("json parser done harusnya... :D");

                            setContentView(R.layout.unitlinklist);
                            LinearLayout unitlink1=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.unitlink1);
                            list=(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);

                            TransaksiUnitAdapter unitlink = new TransaksiUnitAdapter(InvestasiViewerEpolicy.this, 
                                    ListUnitLink);
                            list.setAdapter(unitlink);

                    }
```

is there any wrong in my code? if yes, can you tell me where's my fault and how to fix it? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your activity extend `ListActivity`? Because you are using two ListViews and every time you are calling `setListAdapter()` you are setting the same `ListActivity` adapter. If you want to use several `ListView`'s in one layout, extend your `Activity` from `Activity` and set up adapters and listeners appropriately.

Comment: yup i have extend my activity as ListActivity.. so what's your mean "and set up adapters and listeners appropriately."

Comment: If you are extending ListActivity and using custom layout with ListView inside, your ListView shoud have android:id="@+id/android:list". But in your case you are using several ListViews. So you should extend Activity, set and manage adapters (and f.e. listeners like OnClickListener) separately for each ListView.

Comment: Update you code in question: how are you setting adapters to lists.

Comment: Now you are extending Activity instead of ListActivity. I asked you to attach your new code, where you are setting adapters.

Comment: Check if setContentView(R.layout.unitlinklist) is not setting twice. From your code I can not understand the logic before the if

Comment: thank you for your help.. setContentView(R.layout.unitlinklist) is not setting twice it must one